# I have an input field with 8 underscores for a 8 digit invoice number. How do I make the digit typed replace the underscores?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

As I type a digit into the little dash, the underscore would be replaced by the number I typed.
How do I achieve this using Javascript or Backbonejs. Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: Could you please share code snippet.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to replace all underscores with the entered number you can use `replace()` method with regex `/_*/g` which will replace all underscores with your number. You can use AJAX to do it without reloading too.